# Playa sorting across entries

Tags: playa

I've got a playa field that pulls data from a few entries. I'd like to sort all the results alphabetically. However right now it returns each entry and then alphabetizes each. So I get something like:
Apple
Banana
Cabbage
Alfalfa
Broccoli 
etc

My code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="somechannel" site="default_site"}
{exp:playa:children field="playafield" orderby="title" sort="asc" site="default_site"}
    <li>{title}</li>
  {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried that outside of the channel entries tag?

```
{exp:playa:children field="playafield" orderby="title" sort="asc" site="default_site"}
<li>{title}</li>
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Try the above code alone in your template.  Does that give you the output you need?

Comment: I did try this earlier. It appears to output random channel titles in addition to the playa field selections. However, when I added field_id it worked perfectly. Maybe it has to do with the MSM setup. In any case thank you for the help!

Comment: My pleasure, David!